# Python NAN NAN NAN NAN NAN when I read a .dat file

Tags: python

Ok, im new to Python, I have a .dat file that I want to read, I need to miss the header and it is of the type:

```
header blah blah blah blah blah 10e20 2e46 blah blah blah
10.0    0.0
10.1    0.0
10.2    0.0
10.3    0.0
10.4    0.0
10.5    0.0
```

the numbers on the left are seperated by a tab space

my code thusfar is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as pyplot
import math
import csv
import numpy
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt("file.dat", skip_header=1, delimiter=',')

print data
```

This is the first part of the assignment and i cant even read the file and print the data?? the code worked for other files, but not this one, all i get at the output is

[ nan  nan  nan ...,  nan  nan  nan]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: doesn't look comma-delimited to me...

Comment: Where is the comma delimeter in your text ? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specify delimiter correctly. There's no comma in the given file.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.genfromtxt("file.dat", skip_header=1, delimiter='\t')
array([[ 10. ,   0. ],
       [ 10.1,   0. ],
       [ 10.2,   0. ],
       [ 10.3,   0. ],
       [ 10.4,   0. ],
       [ 10.5,   0. ]])
```

Comment: have you tested this? I had the same thought, but running your code I still get `nan  nan  nan  nan  nan  nan` for the output (with a print statement added.

Comment: @ChrisProsser, Yes I tested. OP's file contains tabs. You can confirm that if you try to edit the question.

Comment: nope, tried it with /t and spaces and a tab, and still get [nan, nan, nan, nan]

thanks for the help, anyone else any ideas?

Comment: oh it's \t, ok that works but now i get this  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\computing\finplanck.py", line 25, in <module>
    data = np.genfromtxt("practice_data_py13rjw.dat", skip_header=1, delimiter='\t')
  File "Q:\PythonXY273_MaPS-T.v01\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1593, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #16 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
    Line #17 (got 2 columns instead of 1)
    Line #18 (got 2 columns instead of 1)

Comment: @user2956523, Works perfect with your given file. See http://asciinema.org/a/6233 .

Comment: @user2956523, Wow! Filename contains `.exe`. !! I cancelled the download!

Comment: what?? just click on the 1.dat bit on the page

Comment: `1.dat bit` ?? I can't see it. If I click **download** button below the page, it start downloading `1.dat.exe`, and it is actually executable file. :(

Comment: At the top after the semi colon of Download:

Comment: @user2956523, Okay, I downloaded. BTW, it's colon, not semicolon(`;`).

Comment: @user2956523, Replace `skip_header=1` with `skip_header=16`. (The file contains some non-csv data).

Comment: thanks guys really appreciated, can get on with trying to plot the data now :-) thanks again! i'll accept the answer in the link above!

Comment: @falsetru okay, I think I went wrong by just copying and pasting the data.dat into a file and the gaps came out as multiple spaces rather than tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where's the comma delimiter in you data? It's more of tabs, or spaces.

```
10.0    0.0
10.1    0.0
10.2    0.0
10.3    0.0
10.4    0.0
10.5    0.0
```

Just change the delimiter parameter to match your data delimiter.

```
data = np.genfromtxt("file.dat", skip_header=1, delimiter='\t')
```

Try it with spaces:

```
data = np.genfromtxt("file.dat", skip_header=1, delimiter='    ')
```

So I tested it now with tabs, it didn't work. I tried it with spaces and it worked fine.

Comment: nope, tried it with /t and spaces and a tab, and still get [nan, nan, nan, nan]

thanks for the help, anyone else any ideas?